# Dual Boot with UEFI Firmware having windows pre-installed in Legacy Mode

Tags: ubuntu, boot, bios

I have bought a new laptop Lenovo Ideapad 310, with Windows 10 Pre-installed in legacy mode, but when I try to install Ubuntu from a DVD or USB some UEFI frimware error is showing up -

"This machine's firmware has started the installer in UEFI mode but it looks like there may be existing OS already installed using BIOS Compatibility Mode, if you continue to install Debian in UEFI mode, it might be difficult to reboot the machine into any BIOS-mode operating systems later"

So it seems like my firmware is UEFI, but Windows 10 was installed in Legacy mode, now, Ubuntu will be installed in UEFI.

I tried changing the boot mode from UEFI to legacy, but then my DVD, USB is not detected.

Kindly guide me on how to dual boot Ubuntu in a UEFI firmware with Windows 10 pre-installed in Legacy mode.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error it is a warning. Your UEFI should be configured with CSM enabled. (most but not all UEFI will actually call it this if not an option like UEFI+Legacy means the same thing).

The short of it is you're already doing what you're suppose to. You're installing Linux in UEFI mode, keeping your UEFI in compatibility mode and Windows installed legacy.

Never the less issues could crop up due to buggy firmware or if you change the partitions on the drive with Windows on it. If you intend to install Linux on the same drive as Windows this will not work due to a limitation in Windows that a drive must be legacy partitioned instead of GPT if its installed in legacy mode.

If you install Linux on separate device you should have no problem except the occasional buggy firmware in which case you'd be forced to install Linux in legacy mode as well.

Your other option is to convert your Windows install to UEFI. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/mbr-to-gpt This process is not user friendly and has caveats. For example it won't convert dynamic disks and that the MBR system partition can't be moved or changed unless its its run from Windows PE (the install disc). It should also work from Windows RE.